# Why does my bandpass RF filter complain about Ts in Simulink?

Tags: filter, matlab, sampling

I am doing a basic amplitude modulator, and I'm using as input signal for now a Gaussian noise generator, then I modulate it with a carrier fc=2e9Hz. When using Simulink along with a RF bandpass filter, I got an error saying that there is missmatch between the filter sampling time (Badnpass filter Ts = 2.5e-9) and the input signal the noise I guess (Ts= 2.5e-11), as it can be seen in the picture attached.

[image: block config]

I have tried as well to set the same sampling time in the gaussian generator and in the filter, but then I got another error saying that the sampling time in the filter is to low compared to the center frequency... Which I don't know what it does mean, since if I set it lower, then I would have aliasing issues.

May someone enlighten me a bit?

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: Did you try setting the sample times the same?

Comment: I have tried as well to set the same sampling time in the gaussian generator and in the filter, but then I got another error saying that the sampling time in the filter is to low compared to the center frequency

Answer (score 1):

> if I set it lower, then I would have aliasing issues.

You said you have a carrier of 2 GHz and a sampling period of 2.5 ns.

You already have aliasing issues.

You need a sampling period of less than 0.25 ns to avoid aliasing.

It may be that you are deliberately undersampling in order to use the sampling process to down-mix your signal. That is a perfectly acceptable technique, although I'm not familiar enough with Simulaink to know if there's any isses with simulating it.

On top of that, if a "Gaussian Noise Generator" is in fact a white gaussian noise generator, then you have an infinite signal bandwidth. (I'm not clear if you are using this as a stand-in for a message signal or to model channel noise)

Try low-pass filtering the noise source down to a small fraction of the carrier frequency before using it to modulate the carrier. If you keep your 400 MSa/s sampling rate, you need to keep the signal bandwidth below 200 MHz to avoid aliasing.

Comment: Hello The Photon, I know that I am having aliasing if I use that sampling period, the thing is that if I change it to 2.5e-11,for instance, I got another error in the same block saying "saying that the sampling time in the filter is to low compared to the center frequency", and for now you are right I don't want to undersample to down-mix my signal.

Comment: Concerning to the the Gaussian Noise generator, we could keep it as I am using it as a message signal. Then, do you suggest me filtering the source with a low-pass filter and a bandwidth of 200MHz before modulating the carrier? Could you explain me a bit more this idea?

Comment: Main point is, white noise has infinite bandwidth. So if you try to use it in place of a message signal, it's not suprising the tool thinks the sampling rate is not sufficient to measure it.